# Object based image editor for Windows

Tags: image

I'm not a designer but I sometimes have to create/edit images for our applications.

In the past I've used "Microsoft Image Composer" - I like its user interface because it's object based and easy to use. Unfortunately it was discontinued and the old version I am using has some problems with png files.

I've tried to find a good replacement but everyone seems to be using layers instead of objects.

Do you know any image editors that are object based?

EDIT:

Still haven't found what I am looking for ... the best alternative so far is Paint.NET even though it uses layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess no such software exists. That's a pity because I found that UI much better than the layer model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Illustrator? As a vector graphics app it might not be exactly "object based", but you work with independent shapes instead of pixel layers.

Inkscape http://www.inkscape.org/ is a free alternative. I haven't tried it, but it seems like a winner.

Comment: I tried Inkscape but vector graphic apps don't offer the features I need. Exporting is also a problem, especially at small images sizes (e.g. icons).

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to what's likely to already be on your machine, both PowerPoint and Visio are object oriented (but crude) image editors.